# Rest Web Service with scala

Tags: scala, rest

I am starting to learn how to build rest Web service (I come from soap web service).

I'm an intermediate scala programer. I'd like to know as of now, what is the most widespread framework for building Restful Service. But i would also appreciate personal opinion on what is the easiest to use for the task of solely building rest api/web-service, very fast, with a not so complicate learning curve.

Many thanks,

-M-

Comment: look at the play! framework.

Comment: Some will recommend Play! frameworks, others will swear by Scalatra

Comment: This isn't the place to look for opinions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Not a question. Everybody can have his opinion based on his experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play, Scalatra and Spray are all good choices with a reasonable learning curve.

You'll have to look at these (and others), then decide which fits best with your own preferences.  It's a **very** subjective question and there are too many variables for anyone to be able to give a definitive answer.